# The probability of two independent random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, self-learning

Let $X, X'$ be independent with $X \sim p(x)$, $X' \sim r(x)$ for $x, x' \in X$.

I don't understand this equation:

$\sum p(x)r(x)=Pr(X=X')$

What is intuitive to me is if $X \sim p(x)$, $X' \sim p(x)$ for $x, x' \in X$, then $\sum p(x)p(x) = Pr(X=X')$.

Could anyone please explain a bit about why $\sum p(x)r(x)=Pr(X=X')$ above? Does it mean that $\sum p(x)r(x) = \sum p(x) p(x)=Pr(X=X')$ ?

Source: http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~cgong821/Wiley.Interscience.Elements.of.Information.Theory.Jul.2006.eBook-DDU.pdf#page=67

Comment: Why do you think that $\sum p(x)p(x) $ (independent of the distribution of $X'$) would equal $\Pr(X=X')$ in general?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the following:

$$ \Pr(X=X') = \sum_{x} \Pr(X=X'\,\vert \, X'=x)\Pr(X'=x)$$

and the right hand side is:

$$ \sum_{x} \Pr(X=x\,\vert \, X'=x)\Pr(X'=x) = \sum_{x} \Pr(X=x)\Pr(X'=x)$$

Comment: Thanks, but I mean the $r(x)$ part.

Comment: I did not fully understand you comment. Isn't $X' \sim r(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

If $X,X'$ are discrete random variables that are independent then:
$$\Pr(X=X')=\sum_x\Pr(X=x=X')=\sum_x\Pr(X=x)\Pr(X'=x)$$where $x$ ranges over a countable set that serves as common support for $X$ and $X'$.

Let me know if things are still not clear.

Comment: or to make it even more clear, you can write the second statement as $$Pr(X=x=X') = Pr(X=x & X'=x) = Pr(X=x)Pr(X'=x)$$ due to independency of X and X'.